# Not displaying polyline on the map in android

Tags: android, line, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime, graphics

I'm new to ArcGIS runtime SDK and I want to add path(polyline) on the map after  giving coordinates where to draw.. But not displaying the path on the map and even not occur any error.

```
MapView mMapView = null;

// The basemap switching menu items.
MenuItem mStreetsMenuItem = null;
MenuItem mTopoMenuItem = null;
MenuItem mGrayMenuItem = null;
MenuItem mOceansMenuItem = null;

// Create MapOptions for each type of basemap.
final MapOptions mTopoBasemap = new MapOptions(MapType.TOPO);
final MapOptions mStreetsBasemap = new MapOptions(MapType.STREETS);
final MapOptions mGrayBasemap = new MapOptions(MapType.GRAY);
final MapOptions mOceansBasemap = new MapOptions(MapType.OCEANS);

ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tms = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");

// The current map extent, use to set the extent of the map after switching basemaps.
Polygon mCurrentMapExtent = null;
GraphicsLayer mLocationLayer;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gis2);


    // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mLocationLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

    mMapView.addLayer(tms);
    // Set the Esri logo to be visible, and enable map to wrap around date line.
    mMapView.setEsriLogoVisible(false);
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);

   SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.GREEN, 3, SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE.DASH);
 Polyline lineGeometry = new Polyline();
 lineGeometry.startPath(-302557, 7570663);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-302959, 7570868);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-303042, 7571220);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-302700, 7571803);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-304043, 7576654);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-300544, 7585289);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-294365, 7592435);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-290122, 7594445);
 lineGeometry.lineTo(-285283, 7595488); 
 Graphic lineGraphic = new Graphic(lineGeometry, lineSymbol);
 mLocationLayer.addGraphic(lineGraphic);

    // Set a listener for map status changes; this will be called when switching basemaps.
    mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
            // Set the map extent once the map has been initialized, and the basemap is added
            // or changed; this will be indicated by the layer initialization of the basemap layer. As there is only
            // a single layer, there is no need to check the source object.
            if ((source == mMapView) && (status == STATUS.INITIALIZED)) {
                boolean mIsMapLoaded = true;
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items from the Menu XML to the action bar, if present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_gis2, menu);


    // Get the basemap switching menu items.
    mStreetsMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    mTopoMenuItem = menu.getItem(1);
    mGrayMenuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    mOceansMenuItem = menu.getItem(3);


    // Also set the topo basemap menu item to be checked, as this is the default.
    mTopoMenuItem.setChecked(true);


    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Save the current extent of the map before changing the map.
    // mCurrentMapExtent = mMapView.getExtent();


    // Handle menu item selection.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.World_Street_Map:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mStreetsBasemap);
            mStreetsMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.World_Topo:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mTopoBasemap);
            mTopoMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.Gray:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mGrayBasemap);
            mGrayMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.Ocean_Basemap:
            mMapView.setMapOptions(mOceansBasemap);
            mOceansMenuItem.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.pause();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.unpause();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your code:

1. You don't add the `GraphicsLayer` to the `MapView`
2. The `Polyline` you are adding to the `GraphicsLayer` is in the wrong spatial reference (should be 102100  (3857))

Graphic Layers do not support on-the-fly reprojection.  When you add a `GraphicsLayer` to your `MapView` you must ensure the spatial reference is the same that is defined on the `MapView`.  You need to ensure that the graphics you add to your graphics layer have coordinates matching the spatial reference, otherwise the graphics may not show up on the map.  I have adjusted your code slightly below:

```
    Envelope initExtent = new Envelope(-10868502.895856911, 4470034.144641369, -10837928.084542884, 4492965.25312689);
    mMapView.setExtent(initExtent, 5);

    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tms = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");

    mMapView.addLayer(tms);

    mLocationLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    mMapView.addLayer(mLocationLayer);

    // Set the Esri logo to be visible, and enable map to wrap around date line.
    mMapView.setEsriLogoVisible(false);
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);

    SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.GREEN, 3, SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE.DASH);
    Polyline lineGeometry = new Polyline();
    lineGeometry.startPath(-10860000, 4475000);
    lineGeometry.lineTo(-10875000, 4475000);
    lineGeometry.lineTo(-10875000, 4488000);
    final Graphic lineGraphic = new Graphic(lineGeometry, lineSymbol);
    mLocationLayer.addGraphic(lineGraphic);
```

Comment: Superb... It worked for me. thnk u :-)